# need to get description of id from another table which are pipe separated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables table1 and table2
in table1 there is a column with name typeids in which ids are pipe separated

```
ex: 2|3|4 --> these ids are the primary key in table2
```

table2 contains Id, Description which has data like

```
2-text1
3-text2
4-text3
```

now I need to get the table1 contents but 2|3|4 will be replaced by

```
text1|text2|text3
```

Comment: Fix your data structure.  Numeric primary keys should never be stored as a delimited string.

Comment: yeah I know but it is already designed so I can't change now, am looking for a solution now

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?  And can you post a full example of your desired output?

Comment: i am using sql 2016 
table1 --> typeIds, name
ex: "1|2|3","text"
table2 --> id,Description
ex:
2-text1
3-text2
4-text3

Now i need output like 
text1|text2|text3,"Text" instead of   "1|2|3","text"

Comment: @RamakrishnaReddy this isn't just bad, it's *very* bad, as in unusable. You can't use any indexes on that data. In SQL Server 2016 you can use `STRING_SPLIT` to get the values as rows. You'll be able to query the data but performance will be *SLOW* and indexing impossible

Comment: @RamakrishnaReddy as for *aggregating* the data, STRING_AGG was added in SQL Server 2017. If the desing isn't fixed you'll have to use one of the other techniques used to aggregate strings using eg XML or SQLCLR

Answer (score 2):

## This is a really poor design of your database and as others have said you should do your level best to get it changed.

---

That said, this is possible.  It is just ugly as sin and I am sure performs like a dog, but you can blame that on your database designer.  In short, you need to split your `id` string on the `|` character, `join` each element to your `table2` and then concatenate them all back together using `for xml`.  As you are using SQL Server 2016 you can use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead of the function I have used below, though as I don't currently have access to a 2016 box here we are ([Working example](http://rextester.com/RRUPS17439)):

```
create function dbo.StringSplit
(
    @str nvarchar(4000) = ' '               -- String to split.
    ,@delimiter as nvarchar(1) = ','        -- Delimiting value to split on.
    ,@num as int = null                     -- Which value to return.
)
returns table
as
return
(
                        -- Start tally table with 10 rows.
    with n(n)   as (select n from (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n(n))
                        -- Select the same number of rows as characters in isnull(@str,'') as incremental row numbers.
                    -- Cross joins increase exponentially to a max possible 10,000 rows to cover largest isnull(@str,'') length.
        ,t(t)   as (select top (select len(isnull(@str,'')) a) row_number() over (order by (select null)) from n n1,n n2,n n3,n n4)
                            -- Return the position of every value that follows the specified delimiter.
        ,s(s)   as (select 1 union all select t+1 from t where substring(isnull(@str,''),t,1) = @delimiter)
                            -- Return the start and length of every value, to use in the SUBSTRING function.
                    -- ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the last value where there is no delimiter at the end of the string.
        ,l(s,l) as (select s,isnull(nullif(charindex(@delimiter,isnull(@str,''),s),0)-s,4000) from s)
    select rn as ItemNumber
            ,Item
    from(select row_number() over(order by s) as rn
                ,substring(isnull(@str,''),s,l) as item
        from l
        ) a
    where rn = @num       -- Return a specific value where specified,
        or @num is null   -- Or everything where not.
)
go

declare @t1 table (id varchar(10));
insert into @t1 values
 ('2|3|4')
,('5|6|7');

declare @t2 table (id varchar(1), description varchar(10));
insert into @t2 values
 ('2','text1')
,('3','text2')
,('4','text3')
,('5','text4')
,('6','text5')
,('7','text6')
;
select t1.id
      ,stuff((select '|' + t2.description
              from @t1 as t1a
                  cross apply dbo.StringSplit(t1a.id,'|',null) as s
                  join @t2 as t2
                      on s.Item = t2.id
              where t1.id = t1a.id
              for xml path('')
             ),1,1,''
            ) as t
from @t1 as t1;
```

Output:

```
+-------+-------------------+
|  id   |         t         |
+-------+-------------------+
| 2|3|4 | text1|text2|text3 |
| 5|6|7 | text4|text5|text6 |
+-------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, yeah I have already suggested about the database design but it is not in my scope to change it.